# How to add acr_values to /user/connect/token request body? ( .net Core )

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, .net-core, oauth

I am trying to get a token for a confidential user from my authentication server.
I created a .NET Core MVC app and used the OAuthExtensions.AddOAuth method to add an authentication service.

To get the token I need to send acr_values to AuthorizationEndpoint and TokenEndpoint. I found out how to send it in the AuthorizationEndpoint request parameters, but I don't know how to add acr_values to the TokenEndpoint request body.
Can anyone help me with this?

My Startup.cs (ConfigureServices):

```
...
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "ClientCookie";
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "ClientCookie";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OurServer";
})
.AddCookie("ClientCookie") // cookie authentication middleware first
.AddOAuth("OurServer", options =>
{
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/my-redirect-path");
    options.ClientId = "ClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://example.com/user/connect/authorize";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://example.com/user/connect/token";
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://example.com/user/connect/userinfo";

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = (context) =>
        {
            context.RedirectUri +=
                "&acr_values=myAcrValues&login_hint=myLoginHint@example.com";
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };

});
...
```

Comment: Does this help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0#openid-connect-aspnet-core-client

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've tried using AddOpenIdConnect. It was not difficult to add the acr_values parameter in it, but it caused many other problems, since I do not have an id_token in the response and I also cannot send a scope openid. I have now decided to use AddOAuth. 
P.S. I have little experience in .NET development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
**Step 1**: Override DelegatingHandler

```
public class CustomAuthorizingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly OAuthOptions _options;
    public CustomAuthorizingHandler(HttpMessageHandler inner, OAuthOptions options) : base(inner)
    {
        this._options = options;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.RequestUri == new Uri(_options.TokenEndpoint))
        {
            string appendData = $"acr_values=myAcrValues&";
            var content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var cntn = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(appendData + content);

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var c in cntn)
            {
                dict.Add(c.Key, c.Value[0]);
            }

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Add it to options in Startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
...
services..AddOAuth("OurServer", options =>
{
    ...
    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new CustomAuthorizingHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), options);
```